# Is there a way to combine parameters to the HttpGet method into an object?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following method in my controller.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MyGetMethod(string address, string zip, int width) {...}
```

It's called via `http://foo.com/home/MyGetMethod?address=234MainSt&zip=90210&width=123`

Is there a way to combine the parameters address, zip and width into an object and have object be passed in to the method in the following manner?

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MyGetMethod(Foo myParam) {...}

public class Foo {
   public string Address {get; set;}
   public string Zip {get; set;}
   public int Width {get; set;}
}
```

There is a vaguely related question for the old ASP.NET MVC that seems to suggest that this is impossible for that technology.

Is it possible with the .NET Core 2.x?

Comment: You can add the `[FromUri]` attribute on `myParam`, see: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/webapi/parameter-binding-in-web-api

Comment: From where you will be calling this API end point? Basically, it is recommended to use POST if you want pass an object. The object will be passed in the body of the request. [NOT RECOMMENDED] : I did a sample end point with type as GET which accepts a model and invoked it from Postman & it worked fine.. But, in GET, we are not supposed to pass an object.

Comment: @Xiaoy312 Thanks.  `[FromUri]` has been deprecated in favor of `[FromQuery]`.  but you got me going in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your data in queryString so you need provider[FromQuery]

> [FromQuery]

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MyGetMethod([FromQuery]Foo myParam) {...}

public class Foo {
   public string Address {get; set;}
   public string Zip {get; set;}
   public int Width {get; set;}
}
```